# fpdf import error in python venv after requirement alreay satisfy

Tags: python, pip, importerror, fpdf, python-venv

I want to install fpdf module for my pdf works but I can't run fpdf command. When i try to install with pip it says requirement already satisfy like this:

```
(electricity) F:\Electriciy Bill>pip install fpdf2
Requirement already satisfied: fpdf2 in f:\electriciy bill\electricity\lib\site-packages (2.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in f:\electriciy bill\electricity\lib\site-packages (from fpdf2) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in f:\electriciy bill\electricity\lib\site-packages (from fpdf2) (9.0.1)
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.3; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'F:\Electriciy Bill\electricity\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

After that when I try to run my code than this happened:

my code:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

def showPdf(details):
    print(details)
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="Room No", ln=1, align="C")
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__name__,"is running")
```

the console output:

```
(electricity) F:\Electriciy Bill>python -u "f:\Electriciy Bill\pdf.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Electriciy Bill\pdf.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fpdf import FPDF
ImportError: cannot import name 'FPDF' from 'fpdf' (unknown location)
```

BTW when I try to run my code with default python env then it runs successfully as like this:

```
F:\Electriciy Bill>python -u "f:\Electriciy Bill\pdf.py"
__main__ is running
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly happened but I uninstall the previous fdf2 module and then again I install fdf2 and then it work properly. :)